# Error Using Grunt neuter with Ember.js RC.3

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs

Using the gruntfile.js from trek's awesome Ember Todos example - https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences - I'm receiving the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

It's strange, because it works perfectly fine with Ember.js RC.1.  Anyone else experience this?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**The Ember Todos uses an old version of neuter**

Rather than edit the `ember.js` file, I found that examining the `package.json` within the excellent example app yielded the solution.

Simply change line 14 to

`"grunt-neuter": "~0.4.0",`

This brings in the updated neuter that has the regex fix which manages to find the `/dependencies/handlebars-runtime.js`.

Comment: fixed as of this commit: https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences/commit/bf48777bf1c7fcc279c1e25f2f8a293f25ab558a

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this was due to an error/conflict with grunt's neuter process and the require() statement in the Ember code itself for Handlebars (line 18358):

```
var Handlebars = this.Handlebars || (Ember.imports && Ember.imports.Handlebars);
if(!Handlebars && typeof require === 'function') {
  Handlebars = require('handlebars');
}
```

I was referencing the rc.3 Handlebar's JS file - name handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3 - so it wasn't finding what it was looking for, a file simply named handlebars.js.  When I changed it to the statement below, all worked fine:

```
var Handlebars = this.Handlebars || (Ember.imports && Ember.imports.Handlebars);
if(!Handlebars && typeof require === 'function') {
  Handlebars = require('handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3');
}
```